# How to avoid a shift reduce conflict in a LALR grammar for parsing nested lists?

Tags: scheme, grammar, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict, bigloo

I would like to create a LALR grammar to parse nested lists, but I get always a shift/reduce conflict.

I have the list1 which is a list of type1 items and list2:

```
<list1> ::= <type1> | <type1> <list1> ;
<type1> ::= A | B | <list2> ;
```

And I have a list2 which is a list of type2 items:

```
<list2> ::= <type2> | <type2> <list2> ;
<type2> ::= X | Y ;
```

This grammar produces a shift/reduce error. How can I avoid it?

This is the concrete [Bigloo](http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/doc/bigloo-13.html#Lalr%281%29-parsing) source:

```
(lalr-grammar 
  (comment
   new-line 
   text-chunk
   white-space)
  (input
   (()                '())
   ((node-list)       node-list))
  (node-list
   ((node)            (cons node '()))
   ((node node-list)  (cons node node-list)))
  (node
   ((comment)         (cons 'comment comment))
   ((new-line)        (cons 'new-line new-line))
   ((text)            (cons 'text text))
   ((white-space)     (cons 'white-space white-space)))
  (text
   ((text-chunk)      (cons 'text text-chunk))
   ((text-chunk text) (cons 'text (string-append text-chunk text)))))
```

The terminals are: comment, new-line, text-chunk and white-space.
The non terminals are: input, node-list, node and text.

Bigloo complains about the reduce rule for text to text-chunk:

```
*** WARNING:bigloo:lalr-grammar
** Shift/Reduce conflict: 
 - shift to state 2
 - reduce rule (text --> text-chunk)
on token `text-chunk'
```

But I do not think that this is a Bigloo problem. It looks like a grammar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar is in fact ambiguous, because a sequence of `type2` instances can be accumulated on `list2` level, but it can also be seen as a sequence of `type1` instances.

E.g. this input

```
 X X
```

can be parsed as

```
 list1(
   type1(
     list2(
       type2(
         X)
       list2(
         type2(
           X)))))
```

but also as

```
 list1(
   type1(
     list2(
       type2(
         X)))
   list1(
     type1(
       list2(
         type2(
           X)))))
```

What about introducing a delimiter on `list1` level? This would solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I was able to solve the problem in two ways. First it is possible to bloat up the grammar to direct the parser in the right way. But the second solution is much more elegant. I is possible to specify a precedence for the type2 terminal in my Bigloo grammar. By that the parser will not treat a list of type2 elements as a list of type1 elements.